# trying to make a link look different when page is clicked in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

well i have seen some similar questions but  i couldn't find the solution i needed i am trying to make it so that when the user moves from one page to another in the website when the page is loaded the a tag should change color and stay that way i have tried using this code but it didnt work at all here is the html of the code

```
 <div id="button-group" style="width:100%">
        <a href="#surprise"><img src="felix.png" id="cat" ></a>
        <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\home.html" style="width:10%" class="button">home</a>
        <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\Hobbies.html" id="hobbies" style="width:10%" class="button">Hobbies</a>
        <a href="#contact_us " style="width:10%" class="button">Contact</a>
        <a href="C:\xampp\htdocs\project\Services.html" style="width:10%" class="button">Services</a>
    </div>
```

so for example if i am on the Hobbies page and click the home page the home page should turn the color to blue or if i am on hobbies and its clicked it should also change color onload 
here is  the jquery  that i tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hobbies").trigger('.click');
});
```

and here is the css when triggered

```
.a :click {
  background-color:rgba(0, 183, 255, 0.788);
  }
```

Comment: Do you mean an *active* state for the link that is the same as the current page?

Comment: You can simply use "onClick" event in HTML itself it will most probably solve the problem.

Comment: @SuhailAkhtar but it switches from one page to another it wont work i guess

Comment: @EmielZuurbier no from one page to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store the link that was clicked and get it when the new page is loaded to set a class to the last clicked navigation element.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    let clicked = $.trim(sessionStorage.getItem("clicked"));
    if (clicked) {
       $("#button-group a").each(function() {
          if ($.trim($(this).attr("href")) == clicked) {
             $(this).addClass("clicked");
          };
       });
    }
    $("#button-group a").on("click", function() {
       $("#button-group a").each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass("clicked");
       });
       let link = $(this).attr("href");
       $(this).addClass("clicked");
       sessionStorage.setItem("clicked", link);
    });
 });
```

As a stack snippet for this doesn't work on Stackoverflow, here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70c18a2u/) with the adjustment to use `preventDefault()` on click of a link. Just run the Fiddle again after clicking on a link to see that the last clicked link gets added the class `clicked`.

Comment: so should i place this code in every page,because home,hobbies,services are all separate files in the project file,because i tried it in one of the files  and it just prevented the default behavior which is to jump to the page

Comment: @Deko96 Yes, this code has to be in every page. Use this version above and not the version in the Fiddle with the preventDefault() adjustment as this is just for demonstration purposes.